# How to recover Ubuntu partition on a dual boot Windows 10 / Ubuntu system?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, partitioning, dualboot

I just got a laptop, in which the previous user had already installed Ubuntu and Windows 10 as dual boot. It gave a reddish (Ubuntu GUI) screen which asked to choose between Windows 10 and Ubuntu.

I was using Windows 10, and there were only two drives C an D which were showing in the explorer. I wanted to create new drive, so:

- I opened windows Disk Management,
- There there were three drives C and D of my Windows and there was also 3rd one, which I assumed was of Ubuntu.
- So I shrank my drive D to get some unallocated space, and it was successful.
- Now I created a drive from this unallocated space and in doing so, it asked whether I wanted to format my new drive, so I clicked OK. The operation was successful. I could see the New drive E with my specified storage size.
- But to my surprise, The drive (where I assumed Ubuntu was installed) was no longer there and it showed only free space of that same size.

[image]

You can see that in the above image:

- To check, I restarted my computer, and yes, there was a Grub rescue error. It said Unknown File system.
- After searching a lot on the internet, I could restore my Windows 10 login through bootable USB and going in the repair menu.
- But the problem is that that drive (Ubuntu) is still showing free space. I thought it would miraculously come back as well. but I was stupid enough to think that.
- Since most of the data of the previous user were on Ubuntu, I could not recover that.

What I want now is to get back my Ubuntu drive so that I can log in again to ubuntu, since another user is going to use ubuntu.

Is there a way to get all that back?

Comment: If you formatted the space then the data was wiped

Comment: That's what I don't understand, I didn't touch that ubuntu drive. I only made a new drive from a drive showing in windows explorer (D), in making so it asks for formating the new allocated free space, and I did so. Did that delete that extra drive (ubuntu), while everyting else C or D was intact?

Comment: Windows by default doesn’t understand Linux file system.  Based on what you describe you wiped your Linux partition

Comment: Oh no, thanks for the quick response. So I can't even recover files (which would be in Linux default file format i guess) instead of recovering partition to run ubuntu?

Comment: You might be able to recover the partition with TestDisk but you performed multiple actions to the disk.  So it’s extremely unlikely

Comment: Alright, might give it a try.